# C# MVC Getting Form data as URL parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a controller that is accepting 3 values from a submitted form, this works fine.

What I need to do now, however is enable a generated link to post the same data to the controller.

The controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Customer(string lastName, string postCode, string quoteRef)
        {

         // Using passed parameters here

        }
```

I am aware routing allows prettier URL's but in this case I need the form to be able to accept the three values either through the submitted form or by the following hyperlink format:

```
path.to.url/Home/Customer?lastName={1}&postcode={2}&quoteRef={3}
```

I have looked into routing but I can't find anything that will allow me to achieve this outcome.

My routes are currently set up as the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Customer",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{lastName}/{postCode}/{quoteRef}", 
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Customer", id = ""}
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =                           UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the form action method to use `GET` instead of POST to send the parameters as query string

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Customer", "Controller", FormMethod.Get
```

Decorate action method with `HttpGet`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Customer(string lastName, string postCode, string quoteRef)
{
}
```

Comment: just to add to that he will also need to lose `[HttpPost]` from his method declaration ;)

Comment: @fr0s1yjack, glad to hear :)

Answer (score 2):

`path.to.url/Home/Customer?lastName={1}&postcode={2}&quoteRef={3}`

this would work only for `[HttpGet]` attribute, not `[HttpPost]`

So your method should look like:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Customer(string lastName, string postCode, string quoteRef)
{

// Using passed parameters here

}
```

And if you still want to use `[HttpPost]`, you should make a little diffrence between `GET` and `POST` method, like here - you cannot have these methods with identical parameters.

URL: `path.to.url/Home/Customer?lastName={1}&postcode={2}&quoteRef={3}&method={4}`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Customer(string lastName, string postCode, string quoteRef, string method)
    { .. }
```